# Querying the length of elements in an expression object with filtering?

Tags: parsing, expression, sapui5

So in my sapui5 view, the following returns a correct answer of 2:

```
<Text text="Test text 1: {= ${notif>CatToPhoto/}.length}"/>
```

This also returns a correct answer of 2:

```
<Text text="Test text 2: {= ${path: 'notif>CatToPhoto/'}.length}"/>
```

This, however, totally ignores the filtering and continues to return an answer of 2 when it should now return 1.

```
<Text text="Test text 3: {= ${path: 'notif>CatToPhoto/', filters: [{path: 'PhotoTypeKey', operator: 'EQ', value1: 2}]}.length}"/>
```

Does anybody know, please, is there a way to perform a filtering of the odata dataset that will allow me to get a count for elements with a certain value?

Comment: is notif a JSONModel?

Comment: No, Marc. It's an ODataModel, v.2.

Answer (score 1):

So I have found that I can achieve what I need to do through the use of a formatter.

An xml sample looks like this:

```
<Text text="Test text: {path: 'notif>CatToPhoto/', formatter: '.filterForOverview'}"></Text>
```

With a formatter function added to a .js file. For simplicity sake here, I've just added it to my Controller.js file, but I will be creating several of these, so I will segragate them out into a formatter.js file:

```
    filterForOverview: function (photos) {
        return photos.filter(photo => parseInt(photo.PhotoTypeKey) === 4).length;
    },
```